# how to partiion with g parted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, resize

hello I have five 2tb hard drives and I would like to make the computer with Ubuntu read all 10 like right now it just shows the one 2tb that has Ubuntu installed on it all the others are their their just not included in the whole drive size like when I right click properties it says the remaining size of the single 2tb hard drive. the other 2 hard drives are their I put extended and Linux swap under the rest of them if this is in correct please tell me what to do.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you are attempting to accomplish. Are you trying to make use of all 10 TB of storage with your Ubuntu installation or are you trying to make all 5 drives appear as a single drive (raid setup) Note that if you setup a raid 5 set you will lose some of the storage capacity to parity.

Comment: What you basically need is software RAID. You probably have to look through the corresponding Ubuntu Wiki page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID. You need RAID 0 (as they say on that page: “If you have 2 x 500 GB HDD then total space become 1 TB”).

Comment: what I am trying to do is use my computer a a server so I can watch TV from it when im not home and I can watch TV in other rooms and record TV

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would not set the swap to over 32gb, or else it gets even slower. There really is no way that I know of to just use them all as one disk, but if you set one as /, another as /home and possibly the other three just for data and have swap on one of the data ones then you will be golden for years to come. Or you could just look up how to set them up in RAID to have complete mirrored backup on all of them

Comment: what do you mean raid i am using this as a server an i would like to use it to record tv and rip my dvds to it so i can watch it when im not home and so my grand father can watch tv also he lives in another state n i sent him a computer to connect to his tv and he can watch tv from my server computer remotely like what would you do

Comment: ripping dvds to show remotely just happens to be very illegal, sorry to say